# Цикл for ведет себя странно (С# WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, for

В одном цикле я постоянно получаю System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:

```
C#
for(int i=0; i<Answers.Count; i++)
{
    Answers[i].BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(() => { Answers[i].Enabled = false; Answers[i].Visible = false; }));
}
```

Длина `Answers` - 6, но при проверке оказалось что `i` достигает 6! Это же невозможно(или я ошибаюсь)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Типичная ошибка с захватом переменной. Попробуйте это

```
for(int i=0; i<Answers.Count; i++)
{
     int j = i;
     Answers[i].BeginInvoke(new InvokeDelegate(() => { Answers[j].Enabled = false; 
           Answers[j].Visible = false; }));
}
```

Проблема в том, что всё, что внутри этого кода `BeginInvoke(....)` запускается не сразу, а через какой то промежуток времени. К тому моменту ваш цикл уже закончился и переменная i уже равна Answers.Count.

Comment: аналогичное поведение было и у цикла foreach до стандарта C# 5.

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev это известный факт, но спасибо, что поделились :)